# Source model "ThemeConfig/catcolumncount" not found for attribute "products_column_count"

Tags: magento-1.8

I have upgraded from 1.7.02 to 1.8.1 - Everything is working fine except when I go into admin and click Catalog>Manager Categories -

I get this:

Source model "ThemeConfig/catcolumncount" not found for attribute "products_column_count"

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a core error.
You have a 3rd party module installed that is not working.

My deductive reasoning deduced it is called 'ThemeConfig'

Have a look why that module is not working.

To explain what is happening here:

This 3rdParty Module installed a new Category Attribute, and attached to it a backend_model of ThemeConfig/catcolumncount (this will now be in your database)

Since that model cannot be located (most likely because that module is not working/installed) the display of that attribute fails.

Comment: I removed those from the database and was able to get back in to category section. Thanks for your quick reply.